# Problem when trying to upload image from Flex to PaperClip with creating thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, paperclip

I'm trying to upload an image from Flex to Rails. It uploads fine if I just want to upload the original but when I tried to add Thumbnail I got the following error:

```
[paperclip] identify '-format' '%wx%h' '/var/folders/RH/RHekFGKME9uDJbX4d4DG3E+++TI/-Tmp-/stream,23830,0.jpeg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/RH/RHekFGKME9uDJbX4d4DG3E+++TI/-Tmp-/stream,23830,0.jpeg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
[paperclip] identify '-format' '%wx%h' '/var/folders/RH/RHekFGKME9uDJbX4d4DG3E+++TI/-Tmp-/stream,23830,0.jpeg[0]' 2>/dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: /var/folders/RH/RHekFGKME9uDJbX4d4DG3E+++TI/-Tmp-/stream,23830,0.jpeg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.>
```

and I noticed for some reason in the DB that when I upload a file from Flex to Rails it puts the photo_content_type is application/octet-stream shouldn't be jpeg or something? I thought that might be the problem.

Do you know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the photo_content_type -- flash is known to not send the correct mime-type, so I recommend you use [mimetype-fu](http://code.google.com/p/mimetype-fu/) to get the real mime-type

If that doesn't solve your problem comment here and include if this is your development environment and if you're on a mac. It sounds like your environment can't find the rmagick binary. Follow these instructions

/config/intializers/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = ‘/opt/local/bin/identify’
```

Alertnative, this has worked for a colleague:

```
unless RAILS_ENV == "production"
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin"
end
```

On my mac, it's in /opt/local/bin/identify ... if you're on a mac, type in "which identify" to find your binary.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I tried your suggestions. mimetype-fu didn't seem to resolve the issue it gave me unknown/unknown. Also adding the other commands didn't seem to resolve the issue :( any ideas?

Comment: Can you look at the file that's saved and confirm that it is a valid jpg/png/whatever image file?

Comment: Yeah I did. I tried multiple PNG/JPEG files. It might be an issue with identify command: 
identify somefile.jpg

and I get the following:

identify

dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/identify
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
.... I posted a question in Super User regarding this.

Comment: I think RMagick is not properly installed. Are you using a mac? It's difficult.

Comment: Yes I'm using Mac. Can you suggest how to to check if it's properly installed? or maybe a link where I can re-install it to make sure it's installed properly.

Comment: Run this code to see: http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1589 .. it created a graph looking .gif file for me

Comment: Thanks @Jesse your suggestions helped. I actually deleted all Mac Ports and reinstalled them then used your code above for Rails and it resolved the problem

Comment: Paperclip.options[:command_path] = '/usr/local/bin' works for me on MacOS